# Keras accuracy never exceeds 19%

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, keras

I am taking the images from the SVHN (street view house number dataset, stanford) and I could really use some help in figuring out why my accuracy does not increase past 19%... This is essentially an MNIST tutorial with more difficult images (other numbers could be off center, blurs, shadows etc..)

I essentially take each image and subtract that image's mean then I normalize to 0-1 (divide by 255.)

The pipeline is simple enough:

- 2 Convolution 2d Layers (32 filters, 3x3)
- MaxPool (2x2)
- Dropout (.25)
- 2 Convolution 2d layers (64 filters, 3x3)
- Max Pool (2x2)
- Dropout(.25)
- Flatten
- Dense Relu
- Dropout(.5)
- Dense Softmax (10)

---

```
1792/73257 [..............................] - ETA: 3:17 - loss: 2.3241 - acc: 0.1602

1920/73257 [..............................] - ETA: 3:16 - loss: 2.3203 - acc: 0.1625

2048/73257 [..............................] - ETA: 3:14 - loss: 2.3177 - acc: 0.1621

2176/73257 [..............................] - ETA: 3:13 - loss: 2.3104 - acc: 0.1682
...
...
...

53376/73257 [====================>.........] - ETA: 51s - loss: 2.2439 - acc: 0.1879

53504/73257 [====================>.........] - ETA: 51s - loss: 2.2439 - acc: 0.1879

53632/73257 [====================>.........] - ETA: 50s - loss: 2.2439 - acc: 0.1878

53760/73257 [=====================>........] - ETA: 50s - loss: 2.2439 - acc: 0.1879
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Are there any tips to figuring out why it would increase in the beginning as normal then taper off so quickly?

I am using categorical cross entropy with an rmsprop optimizer

epochs: 20
batch_size: 128
image_size: 32x32

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3),
                        strides=1,
                        activation='relu',
                        padding='same',
                        input_shape=input_shape,
                        data_format='channels_last'))


model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last'))


model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(model.output_shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

#METHOD1
# print('compiling model...')
# model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
#               optimizer='sgd',
#               metrics=['accuracy'])
# print('fitting model...')
#
# model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=1, verbose=1)


# METHOD2
sgd = SGD(lr=0.05)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          epochs=20,
          batch_size=128)
score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
```

Comment: post your code here please

Comment: Is there a way for me to ask this question in a better way? Wondering why I got downvote

Comment: add your code first

Comment: just added, thanks

Comment: quick help: try nadam optimizer, and reduce number of filters for Con2d

Comment: Do I need to change the loss? I am using categorical cross entropy, also what are some recommended filter sizes? Sorry, noob here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160023/discussion-between-paddy-and-codebrotherone).

Comment: Maybe do some image [augmentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)